# Concatenar en la misma posición un array

Tags: javascript, php, script

Tengo un problema al tratar de unir 2 array, mi intención es concatenar pero solo en la posición que ocupa y con un espacio de por medio entre cada elemento.
Sea el caso por ejemplo:(con 3 elementos cada uno)

```
> Array1 = ["2019-09-19","2019-09-19","2021-09-19"] 
> Array2 =  ["13:58:00","13:59:00","14:58:00"]
> 
> **Resultado deseado**
> 
> Resul =["2019-09-19 13:58:00","2019-09-19 13:59:00","2021-09-19
> 14:58:00"]
```

Desde ya, agradecería mucho una ayudita!!!!

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Además, ¿qué tiene que ver sql y mysql con la pregunta? Pon solo las etiquetas que corresponden: ¿JS o PHP? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

en JS

```
let Array1 = ["2019-09-19","2019-09-19","2021-09-19"] 
let Array2 =  ["13:58:00","13:59:00","14:58:00"]

let result = Array1.map((item,index) => {

    if(Array2[index]){
      return `${item} ${Array2[index]}`
    }

})
```

en PHP

```
$arr1 = ["2019-09-19","2019-09-19","2021-09-19"];
$arr2 = ["13:58:00","13:59:00","14:58:00"];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $posicion=>$value) {
    if($arr2[$posicion]){
        $result[]= $value." ".$arr2[$posicion];  
    }
    
}
```

Comment: y como se podria hacer para PHP y almacenarlos en un nuevo array el resultado

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. De hecho, aguarda a que OP edite su pregunta para dar más aclaraciones. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.